# Как мне вызвать переменную находящуюся в функции Thread3() из функции main(), находящейся в функции Thread2()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Весь код:

```
from DataBase_0_2_0 import *
import json
import pyttsx3
import os
import sys
import speech_recognition as sr
import time
import datetime
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import webbrowser as wb
from threading import Thread


filename = "settings.json"

#=============================================================Датабаза
def Thread1():
    def _save(settings):
        with open (filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(settings, f, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)
            f.close()
    Thread1._save = _save
 
    def _getDate():
        with open (filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            load = json.load(f)
            dates = list(load.values())
            return dates
            f.close()
    Thread1._getDate = _getDate

#==============================================================

    def speak(what): # Сказать
        print(what)
        x = pyttsx3.init()
        x.say(what)
        x.runAndWait()
        x.stop
    Thread1.speak = speak

    def hear(): # Записать
        global error
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as source:  # Запись аудио
                r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.6)  # шумоподавление
                print("Скажите что-нибудь: ")
                audio = r.listen(source)
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU") # Преобразование речи в текст
            error = 0 # Возвращает 0 в ложные запросы
            return text.lower()  # Возврат
        except:
            return hear()
    Thread1.hear = hear

    def debug_Mode(): # Режим отладки
        speak("Введи ключ доступа")
        cod = input("--> ")
        if cod == "2004":
            speak("Запускаю режим отладки")
            print("=" * 40)
            mod = True
        else:
            speak("Ошибка доступа")

        while mod == True:
            zapros = hear()
            print("[log]:" + zapros)
            if zapros == "выход":
                mod = False
                speak("закрываю режим отладки")
                print("=" * 40)
    Thread1.debugMode = debug_Mode

    def Search(zapros): # Функция поиска
        speak("Открываю в поиске: " + zapros)
        url = "https://www.google.ru/search?q=" + zapros
        wb.open_new(url)
        play = False
    Thread1.search = Search


def Thread2():
    def main(): # Главная функция
        settings = {}
        date = Thread1._getDate()

        Thread1.speak("Здравствуй, я голосовой ассистент Юля. Версия 0.2.0. Не закрывайте окно, иначе вам нужно будет перезапустить меня чтобы его вернуть.")

        while True: # Главный цикл

            request = Thread1.hear() # Прослушмваем

            result = [key for key, val in database.items() if request in val]  # Проверяем наличие нашего запроса в базе, помещаем ответ в переменную
            result = "".join(result)  # Преобразуем список в строку

            if result:

                if result == "Режим отладки":
                    Thread1.debug_Mode()

                elif result == exit_:
                    Thread1.speak(result)
                    os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM Yulia_0_2_0_Demo.exe")

                elif result == Real_Need:
                    Thread1.speak(result)

                elif result == Your_History:
                    Thread1.speak(result)

                elif result == Program1:
                    global Program
                    global Program1way
                    Program1way = Program.get()
                    settings['Program1way'] = Program1way
                    Thread1._save(settings)
                    Thread1.speak(result)

                elif result == Program1Start:
                    db = _getDate()
                    OneWay = db[0]
                    os.startfile(OneWay)
                    Thread1.speak(result)

                elif result == Programnumber2:
                    global Program2
                    global Program2way
                    Program2way = Program2.get()
                    settings['Program2way'] = Program2way
                    Thread1._save(settings)
                    Thread1.speak(result)

                elif result == Program2Start:
                    db = _getDate()
                    SecondWay = db[1]
                    os.startfile(SecondWay)
                    Thread1.speak(result)

                elif result == FindIt:
                    Thread1.speak("Скажите запрос")
                    Findit = Thread1.hear()
                    Thread1.Search(Findit)

                elif result == Csgo:
                    Thread1.speak(result)
                    os.startfile("steam://rungameid/730")

                elif result == Check:
                    Thread1.speak(result)

                else:
                    Thread1.speak(result)
            else:
                Thread1.speak("Команда не распознана")
                continue
    main()



#=========================================================== Ход работы

def Thread3():

    def _from_rgb(rgb): # Для работы TKinter
        return "#%02x%02x%02x" % rgb

    error = 0
    root = tk.Tk() # Задаем новое окно

    root.geometry('400x500') # Определяем размеры
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # Закрепляем размеры
    root.title("Голосовой ассистент Юля")

#======= Непонятный код ======

    image = Image.open("Background.png")
    width = 500
    ratio = (width / float(image.size[0]))
    height = int((float(image.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
    image = image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
    canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=image)

#==============================

    canvas.create_text(200, 25, text="Юлия 0.2.0 Демо", fill="Purple", font='Helvetica 30') # Текст
    canvas.create_text(200, 50, text="Голосовой помощник, созданный для помощи", fill="Purple", font='Times 13') # Текст
    Program = tk.Entry(root, width=61)
    Program2 = tk.Entry(root, width=61)
    canvas.create_text(200, 75, text="Программа №1", fill="Purple", font='Times 13')
    canvas.create_window((10, 85), anchor="nw", window=Program)
    canvas.create_text(200, 115, text="Программа №2", fill="Purple", font='Times 13')
    canvas.create_window((10, 125), anchor="nw", window=Program2) 
    root = tk.mainloop() # Запуск окна
Thr1 = Thread(target=Thread1)
Thr2 = Thread(target=Thread2)
Thr3 = Thread(target=Thread3) 
Thr1.start()
Thr2.start()
Thr3.start()
#==========================================================
```

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Programming\Python3.9.2\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "F:\Programming\Python3.9.2\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "F:\Programming\Yulia\Yulia_0_2_0_Demo.py", line 160, in Thread2
    main()
  File "F:\Programming\Yulia\Yulia_0_2_0_Demo.py", line 118, in main
    Program1way = Program.get()
NameError: name 'Program' is not defined
```

Я уже и global попытался, но не помогло.

Comment: Попробуй создать переменную выше, а присвоить значение ей в том месте, где она сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Никак, это абстракция видимости.  Можно создать переменную уровнем выше и что значит "вызывать переменную", тут не ясно.

```
 n = 10 
 def main():   
    global n
    ticket = n
```

Вы можете отделить функционал и сделать на выходе что бы главная функция вернула что-то для вас важное, что используется в другой функции.

```
n = 10
def main():   
  global n
  ticket = n  
  return ticket - 3 

def methods(): 
  answer = main()
  print(answer)   

  methods()
```

Можно попробовать создать функцию выше, а ее результат записывать абстракцией ниже.

Еще можно где-то хранить данные. В js это LocalStorage